# Show that $\text{card}\left(\frac{\mathbb Z^n}{f(\mathbb Z^n)}\right)=|\det(M)|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

> Let $f:\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb Z^n$ be a group homomorphism represented with respect to the standard matrix $M\in M_n(\mathbb Z)$, and assume that $\det(M)$ isn't $0$.  Show then that $\text{card}\left(\frac{\mathbb Z^n}{f(\mathbb Z^n)}\right)=|\det(M)|$.

I want to try and show both directions, I think that's the approach to take.  The problem is I'm confused with the question itself, mainly the part "represented with respect to the standard matrix $M\in M_n(\mathbb Z)$", I don't really understand what the question is asking.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $n=3$ just so I can give an example. In general such an $f$ would be given by $f(x,y,z)=(a_1x+b_1y+c_1z,a_2x+b_2y+c_2z,a_3x+b_3y+c_3z)$. If I use the standard basis $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$, this function be expressed using matrix multiplication as $$f(x,y,z) = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{array} \right]\left[ \begin{array} {c} x\\y\\z\\\end{array}\right] $$

The matrix $M= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{array} \right]$ is called the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to the standard basis.

A good exercise would be for you to think and figure out what this matrix would be if we used  some other basis instead. :)